# Mongodb find query on timestamp with date

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to do a find query on a timestamp field with a date like '2016-02-24' in MongoDB?

I need to do the same thing than in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE from_unixtime(timestamp/1000) = '2016-02-24 00:00:00'
```

But I don't find anything to do this :-(

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query MongoDB by Unix style timestamp using the following queries:

Example 1. Check for certain date

```
db.data.find({"createdOn":new Date("24 Feb 2016").getTime()/1000} )
```

Example 2. Check where date is less than or equal to specified date

```
db.data.find({"createdOn":{$lte:new Date("25 Feb 2016").getTime()/1000}} )
```

Example 3. Check where date is greater than or equal to specified date

```
db.data.find({"createdOn":{$gte:new Date("25 Feb 2016").getTime()/1000}} )
```

I have used this test data:

```
use test

db.data.save({createdOn:(new Date("24 Feb 2016").getTime()/1000)} )
db.data.save({createdOn:(new Date("31 Dec 9999").getTime()/1000)} )
```

Comment: new Date("24 Feb 2016") give me a ISODate and not a timestamp. It's doesn't work with my DB.

Comment: I have changed the answer to save dates as Unix timestamps

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I want :-)
I add an example with an hour: "createdOn": {$gte:new Date("24 Feb 2016 06:01:17").getTime()}